# How to compare hours and minutes in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, time

I have a users "hours worked" stored in SQLite as `HH:MM` in my Android application. I **do not** want to change the way this data is stored, if possible. That would be a nightmare. I want them to be able to search entries in which their time is `=`,`<`, or `>` another timestamp.

For example, using my app they can make a `WHERE` clause like the following: `time(Hours) > time('5:51')` where `Hours` is the column name. However, I can't seem to get any results, even if I *know* there's a matching row.

Am I doing something wrong? I don't get any exceptions, just no results.

Comment: Q: What do you mean you have "hours worked" stored in SQLIte as "HH:MM"?  Do you mean you actually have a "char(5)" column with rows like "10:15"???

Comment: @paulsm4, SQLite does not have static typing.  See [the docs](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: Picky picky ... but correct.  The point is that a real like "10.25" (for 10h 15m) is better than a text string like "10:15".  Or a start date/time and corresponding end date/time might also be a better solution.  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4, I was pointing out that he didn't leave anything useful out of the question.  Knowing it is a string was enough.  The problem with a REAL is that you lose precision, which people can be touchy about when it comes to paychecks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

time will not accept durations unless they are coincidentally also valid times.  So even though someone can work 40 hours:

```
SELECT (time('40:00') IS NULL);
```

gives 1 (showing it's an error).

```
SELECT (time('11:00') IS NULL);
```

is 0.  But presumably both need to work.

Luckily, if you stick to two-digit hours and two-digit minutes, you can compare them as ordinary strings.

```
SELECT '84:13' > '29:03';
1

SELECT '05:12' > '43:58';
0
```

**EDIT**: A better solution might be to simply store the number of minutes as an INTEGER (one of the SQLite [base types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)).  Yes, you need to do a one-time upgrade conversion, but I think it's a better choice.

You have complete precision, you can easily multiply (e.g. by an hourly rate), and it's a simple modulus if you want to display as HH:MM in some report.

Comment: +1 for showing `time('40:00')` will never work. However, sticking to 'HH:MM' sounds like as much of an issue as "not changing" the format .. as there are plenty of counter-examples, e.g. `'5:12' > '43:58'` and `'11:00' > '100:00'`, if the format isn't 100% like that.

Comment: No way.. so it'll just convert the strings as needed and compare them as integers?

Comment: No, it compares them as strings.  But since the Unicode ordering is the same as the desired ordering, it works.  It's similar to the reason ISO 8601 (the date format) sorts as strings automatically.  Everything is laid out the same (most significant left, colon always the same place).

Comment: I've just modified my code and I can confirm this works.. Thanks Matthew!